# I would like to model this shape, but can't figure out how. I've tried booleans, modeling it and even connecting different shapes

Tags: modeling

As I said, ive tried quite some techniques, but none of them leave me with a clean enough topology to bevel the sides.

[image: The shape I would like to model]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 7):

Create a cube, remove its top face, scale the top edges except the back that seems to stay vertical:

[image]

Extrude up the back:

[image]

Bevel the edges:

[image]

Bevel the top vertices, create this topology:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to extrude faces along normals, bevel the edges to keep them sharp, give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]use the subd workflow you and
add edge control
the bottom face can be grid fill

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.